# jQuery does not execute correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Esileht</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prax2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stuff">
        <a href="" class="btn" id="stuff_btn">START</a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="span10" id="word_place">
        <div class="word_grid" id="word_place_grid">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script src="prax2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the jQuery that does not run properly in the prax2.js file:

```
$('#stuff_btn').on('click', function(){
    var words = ["arvuti","pudel","mudel","blaaah","shfuiah","ashcfah"];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    var word = words[random];   
    var chars = word.split('');
    chars = _.shuffle(chars);
    for(var i in chars)
    {
        $('#word_place_grid ul').append('<li class="letter">' +  i +  '</li>');
    }
})
```

The problem is that I want to add the letters that have been shuffled to an `ul`. Each letter beeing a `li`. The problem is that all I get there are numbers from 1-6 and when I try to log the results in between the running of that script, then sometimes I get the result in the console and sometimes not, and it always shows for only a millisecond or so.

Can anyone spot the problem? Is it in my html or script or maybe somewhere else?

Comment: what does your console say? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle for that?

Comment: Don't use `for ...  in` for arrays.

Comment: `chars[i]` is what you want

Answer (score 3):

You're using a `for-in` statement, which iterates over the keys/properties of the array.

```
for(var i in chars)...
```

`i` within the for refers to the indexes, not the actual elements of the array. Although, `chars[i]` would work here, it would also print any other properties added to `Array.prototype`.
That is, `Array.prototype.someProperty = 'a property'` would result in `'a property'` being displayed.

Use

```
for(var i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i ++) {
   //use the value of chars[i];
}
```

Or better use `forEach`:

```
chars.forEach(function(ch) {
  $('#word_place_grid ul').append('<li class="letter">' +  ch +  '</li>');
});
```

This example works.

[**JS Bin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/OmeBiSO/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You've attached your event handler to a link (to the current page).

The JS runs. The document update. The link gets followed. The page is reloaded.

Use an `<input type="button">` if you want to have interactivity that only works with JS.

If you want to use a link, then link to a server side script with equivalent functionality ([progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) is good) and then cancel the default behaviour of the event if the JS runs successfully.

```
$('#stuff_btn').on('click', function(evt){ // Capture the event object
// ...
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you see the number because of the for loop where i is the index. Try:

```
for(var i in chars)
{
    $('#word_place_grid ul').append('<li class="letter">' +  chars[i] +  '</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour of `<a>`. and make sure your script is inside `document.ready` function

```
$(function(){
$('#stuff_btn').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var words = ["arvuti","pudel","mudel","blaaah","shfuiah","ashcfah"];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
var word = words[random];   
var chars = word.split('');
chars = _.shuffle(chars);
for(var i in chars)
{
  $('#word_place_grid ul').append('<li class="letter">' +  i +  '</li>');
}
})
});
```